# Preserve Cell Image After Scrolling UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell which acts as a check list.  As the user clicks on the selected item, it goes from red to green indicating a selection, however as the users scrolls further down the list, once they come back up to the top, the image has changed back to it's default red value.

How do I go about preserving the state of an image as the tableview recycles cells?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using the `UITableViewCell`s to store the state of your table data. This is the wrong approach because the cells are reused. You should keep state in an separate 'data store'. This can simply be an array you keep in memory in your `UITableViewController` subclass or something persistent like SQLite or Core Data. This state is then transferred back to the cell when the table view asks you to in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Use:

```
MyTableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyTableViewCell"];
if (cell == nil) { /* create cell */ }
/* and now you reset the properties of that cell */
cell.text = [myCellText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

The key here is to **reset the properties of dequeued table cell based on the indexPath**.   This does mean you will have to keep around enough state to re-create any table cell--**including the images you are using**.